# Strange noise when at low speed on 2014 Toyota Harrier

Tags: toyota, noise, harrier

I am getting the following sound on a Toyota Harrier 2014. 2WD.

YouTube video:

https://youtu.be/GDv4_Pw4Fyw

The noise goes away when I accelerate.

I have exhausted mechanics trying to fix this issue.

Over 3000USD spent, change mounts and some work was done on transmission belt and pulley replacement.

Vehicle Specs:

Toyota Harrier :Model : DBA- ZSU60W-ANXGP
Engine: 3ZR-FAE

TRIM: FA43
Transmission: K114- 01A

Please help :(

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does the knocking noise sound like it is coming from the transmission internals?

Comment: Sounds like it coming where the drive shaft connects but the tripod bearing is ok. Not sure if torque converter or flex plate